# Blender Glossy Direct render pass

Tags: rendering, render-passes

I was thinking that I know very well Cycles Render passes, but not. 
Can someone explain Me (I was searching on web, but with no success), why Glossy direct pass is taking texture into consideration? Not environment, but texture on object?

This is an example (apologize for that simple texture). So in this case, We are unable to use Blender UV pass? Because if, I have to render a product, and 2 identical (in UV space) textures. And I like to use UV pass to just change Diffuse Color pass, I can't? Because Glossy Direct will deliver something from original one?

Here's the Combined pass:
[image: Combined]
Here's the Glossy pass:
[image: Glossy pass]

Also it's not taking the color information, but only value. So Glossy pass is taking into consideration BW version of original texture to somehow deliver reflection inforamtion? It looks like that, or this is a Blender bug.

Tested on normal Glossy shader mixed with diffuse, on Principled, on CynicatPro shader, always the same behavior.

Regards, 
Kamil.

Comment: Hmm I am not able to reproduce your issue.  I've tried a glossy direct pass on objects with various textures (image textures, checker textures, magic texture) and the texture does not show up in the glossy pass.  Are you sure your texture is not somehow going into the glossy color inputs?
  Could you maybe post your blend file?

Comment: Hi, 

Yes please, here is a test blend, with texture. See glossy direct pass after rendering, something weird is happening. 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C0Hwb5yxFRfcD6Kxzg6YARTKWyMtQX_A

Also what version of Blender are You using, this was tested on official 2.79. But also on newest from builder.blender and always the same. 

Regards, 
Kamil.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Glossy Direct pass looks like when your file is rendered on my system.  I am using official Blender 2.79.  I do not see any trace of the image texture, which is visible in the Combined pass.  The other passes come out as expected as well.

[image]

Comment: Risingfall, take a look closer, it occurs. Or add RGB curves adjustment to see this better. So this is the same, exactly the same. So I have no idea what is wrong. I don't even know where to find this. I will post on bugtracker.

Comment: Yes, I see it but only when making the RGB curves adjustment.  That's pretty strange!

Comment: Added to Blender bug tracker. Will inform here. 

Regards, 
Kamil.